# Calculations coming out to 0.0?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

A simple percentage calculation. It wont return a value except 0.0 and I think once or twice it returned 100.0%. Other than that it won't do a thing. I have tried playing with the code in several different ways and it just wont work.

```
for (int loop = 1; loop < loopCount; loop++)
            {
                aa = r.nextInt(10+1);
                abc = (int) aa;

                String[] userAnswer = new String[x];

                int totalQues = (correctAnswer + wrongAnswer), actualQues = (totalQues - 1);

                if(abc < x)
                {
                    userAnswer[abc] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Question "+quesNum+"\n\n"+questions[abc]+"\n\nA: "+a[abc]+"\nB: "+b[abc]+"\nC: "+c[abc]+"\nD: "+d[abc]+"\nCorrect Answers: "+correctAnswer+"\nWrong Answers: "+wrongAnswer+"\nTotal Questions: "+totalQues);

                    if(userAnswer[abc].equals(answers[abc]))
                    {
                        correctAnswer++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        wrongAnswer++;
                    }//else

                    if(actualQues == x);
                    {
                        score = (correctAnswer / actualQues) * 100;

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The test is finished.");

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You scored "+score+"%");

                    }//if

                }//if

            }//for
```

Comment: aa = r.nextInt(10+1)

Is there a reason you are doing this?  This is the same thing as aa = r.nextInt(11).  You may be wanting aa = r.nextInt(10) + 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
score = (correctAnswer / actualQues)
```

If both `correctAnswer` and `actualQues` are int's then score will get 0 every time, because int values can't handle decimal values, thats why we use floating point.

`correctAnswer` and/or `totalQues` should be float/  double ( BigDecimal to be pedantic). That way, with one of the operands being a floating point value, the division is done in floating point arithmetic, instead of integer arithmetic..and SHAZAM!, you'll get a non-zero (non-truncated) result.

Answer (score 4):

Change

```
score = (correctAnswer / actualQues) * 100;
```

to

```
score = ((double)correctAnswer / actualQues) * 100;
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are doing integer division, the result of that operation will always be either 0 or 1. Instead, try casting to a floating-point number prior to dividing:

```
score = (int)((correctAnswer / (1.0 * totalQues)) * 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming both `correctAnswer` and `totalQues` are integer types, the line `score = (correctAnswer / totalQues) * 100;` will use integer division (resulting in 0 or 1). To avoid this, you need to explicitly cast one to a floating type:

```
score = (correctAnswer / ((double)totalQues)) * 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast (*or even declare*) the attributes to "**double**" type. That should work out for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need, or want a double, the simplest solution is to do the multiplcations first.

```
score = 100 * correctAnswer / actualQues;
```

In this case, score remains an int value.